# how to implement an infopath form which contains varying number of items

Tags: infopath, list-form

In our corporation we have a paper form which is filled by parents. For example a father should write different specifications about himself, and name and birth date of his family. Obviously he can have several children.

So to implement this form, I should have 2 lists, say 'parents' and 'children'. Each paper form will add one record to 'parents' list and a varying number of records to 'children' list because parents may have different number of children.

The question is how to implement an infopath form to let users enter data about their children when they may have 1 or 2 or ... or even no children? I have no idea what should it look like?

Any idea is of great help.

Comment: Seeing the tag `list-form` in the question: repeating sections, as suggested by Rob D'Oria don't work in list forms. For that you need a parent-child relationship. This cannot be done with list forms. Did you try this before you accepted the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to implement a repeating section or table.  These are native controls in the designer that can be used in forms that our filled out with the filler desktop app or in the browser.

Whether you choose a repeating section or repeating table will depend on your requirements.  Think of a repeating table as a grid with a header, rows, and columns for each entry, whereas a repeating section is really a collection of freeform canvases, one for each entry.

It sounds like a repeating table would work for what you're trying to do.

Google **InfoPath Repeating Table** or **InfoPath Repeating Section** for details.